# WPF Custom Control That Displays Content Inline or in a Popup

Tags: c#, wpf, popup, custom-controls, contentpresenter

I am creating a custom WPF content control that has a DisplayMode property which can be:

- Inline
- Popup

When DisplayMode="Inline", my ControlTemplate can use a standard ContentPresenter like normal.

However, when DisplayMode="Popup", I want the Content to be displayed in a Popup control.

How should I solve this problem?

Does it have to happen purely in code when the DisplayMode property changes? How do I move the content of the Content property between a ContentPresenter and the Popup?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like I was trying to make this more complex than it really is.

The solution to this was to create two separate ControlTemplate(s). One that displays inline and one that displays in a Popup control.

Next, all I had to do was create a couple style triggers that change the ControlTemplate based on the value of the DisplayMode property.

It looks like this:

```
<Style x:Key="MyControlStyle" TargetType="{x:Type my:MyControl}">
    <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource InlineTemplate}"/>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding DisplayMode}" Value="Inline">
            <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource InlineTemplate}"/>
        </DataTrigger>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding DisplayMode}" Value="Overlay">
            <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource OverlayTemplate}"/>
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```